# Can any domain register support any TLD if domain is transferred there?

Tags: domain-registration, top-level-domains

There are some domain registers out there that support certain TLD's that others do not. My question, is can you register a domain with a special TLD at one register and then transfer the domain name to another register that you could NOT have used to register the domain name because they didn't support that TLD?

Like for example lets pretend that I want to register www.whatever.gr.com at HotRegister.com. Then lets say you don't like their domain name hosting service so you want to transfer it to GoDaddy. But on GoDaddy you can't register a .gr.com domain name to begin with.

So are you able to transfer your .gr.com domain there or can they not support it? Or can any register support any TLD but only choose to allow certain ones to be registered through them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't. The registrar has to have a contract with the organisation that manages the TLD.

Note also that gr.com is not a TLD; com is a TLD and someone has registered gr.com and is selling subdomains. But because it's not an official TLD, many of the safeguards that you get when registering a domain name do not exist.

Comment: Thanks. I was just using .gr.com as an example, but that you for the answer.

Comment: @Jakobud - the [Top-Level Domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) in `.gr.com` is `.com`